# Unhide all Hidden Excel Columns Without Individual Iteration?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Is it possible to unhide all hidden columns of an excel worksheet?

this is my code to unhide all hidden rows. I don't want to additionally check how far the used range of columns goes and iterate through it.

```
foreach (string filePath in _allFiles)
        {
            try
            {
                _wb = _app.Workbooks.Open(filePath, ReadOnly: false);

                foreach (Excel.Worksheet ws in _wb.Worksheets)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string abc = ws.Name;
                        ws.ShowAllData(); /* needs try catch 'cause if no filters are applied, it will throw an exception */
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {   }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {   }
            finally
            {
                _wb.Save();
                _wb.Close();
                //_app.Quit();
                //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_app);
            }
        }
        _app.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_app);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that to determine how to a specific action should be done, is to create a vba macro of the process. Then translate the macro into interop calls.

What I have found is that for each workbook, one can call and set (*as shown in VBA macro*) the columns and rows collection as such:

```
Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
```

You still have to iterate between the workbooks and to call the appropriate C# interop methods.

Comment: The tag Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = false doesn't work. But for columns it works like a charm, thank you! ws.ShowAllData(); works well for rows.